# Create an image with a single, solid color with C++

Tags: c++, image, png

I want to create a PNG (or other format) image that is a single, solid color.  How can I do this in C++?

Comment: PNG is a really, really hard format for beginners. Start with BMP (if confident) or PPM (which is extremely easy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any common format is acceptable, write a PPM file, which is a text file that looks like

```
P3 2 3 255
255 0 0
255 0 0
255 0 0
255 0 0
255 0 0
255 0 0
```

The first line is the PPM header:
"P3" identifies the file format,
"2" is the width,
"3" is the height,
"255" is the range of sample values (0..255).

"255 0 0" is a red pixel (red=255, green=0, blue=0).
Repeat "255 0 0" until you've defined width*height pixels.

Then, if you need PNG, use ImageMagick, GraphicsMagick, or another converter to make a PNG from the PPM file.  There are C++ bindings for both ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick if you'd like to do that within your program, or you can just use the commandline:

```
convert file.ppm file.png
```

or

```
gm convert file.ppm file.png
```

The only problem with PPM is that it doesn't support alpha so this approach is a little more complicated if an alpha channel is needed.  One way is to put the alpha in a separate PGM file (like PPM but only one channel) and then merge them with ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick.

Edited in by Mark Setchell... there is a good description [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) if you want further information on Glenn's great suggestion.

Comment: Way to go, Glenn! I hope you don't mind my adding in a link.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sure, go ahead.  Incidentally, although I'm very familiar with libpng, I almost invariably use PPM or PPM+PGM when I want to create an image from scratch, from a shell script, Fortran program, simple C program, or anything that can write a plain text file.

Comment: Yep, me too - it's simple, consistent and predictable.